# length of large and small axis of the ellipse

Tags: geometry

I need to calculate this elipse:

$c^2=4x_1^2+3x_2^2-2\sqrt{2}x_1x_2$; where $c^2=1, c^2=4$

I need to calculate direction and the length of large and small axis of the ellipse.

(hint: own vector and Eigenvalues)

Comment: This is not an ellipse.  It would be if the last term were $ax_1x_2$, but not with the square root sign.  It doesn't look anything close.  See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4%3D4x^2%2B3y^2-sqrt%288xy%29  There are no points in the second or fourth quadrant (why?)

Comment: This is excercise I need to calculate and I was told that this is an ellipse. any other idea how to calculate?

Comment: I would guess the equation should be $c^2=4x_1^2+3x_2^2-2\sqrt2\ \ x_1x_2$, which is a nice ellipse.  See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4%3D4x^2%2B3y^2-sqrt%288%29xy  Changing $c^2$ from $4$ to $1$ just cuts the size in half.  Can you do it with this equation?

Comment: If you can help even more it would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume the equation is $c^2=4x_1^2+3x_2^2-2\sqrt2\ \ x_1x_2$, as that is an ellipse.  If you are supposed to use an eigenvalue approach, the matrix corresponding to your form is $\begin {pmatrix} 4&-\sqrt 2 \\ -\sqrt 2&3 \end {pmatrix}$.  To find the eigenvalues you need to find the $\lambda$ such that $\left| \begin {array}  &4-\lambda &-\sqrt 2 \\ -\sqrt 2 & 3- \lambda \end {array} \right |=0$.  Then you find the eigenvectors.  The one corresponding to the larger eigenvalue is the one along the major axis, the other is along the minor axis.

Comment: @ Ross: thanks. The equasion was what you wrote. Thanks for your help.